# Для чего нужно вызывать lseek в данном коде

Tags: c, системное-программирование

Программа создает временный файл в `/tmp/` после чего записывает туда данные `Hello World!` из буфера, после успешной записи в файл нужно прочитать содержимое файла и вывести это в `stdout`. Проблема в том, что я не могу понять зачем использовать системный вызов `lseek`. Да, я заметил что программа без него не работает и последующий вызов `read` не получится, но почему так происходит?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int fdtmp, n;

  char buffer[1024] = "Hello World!";
  char template[] = "/tmp/main_tmp-XXXXXXXXX"; /* имя временного файла */
  if ((fdtmp = mkstemp(template)) == -1) {     /* mkstemp вернет fd нового файла */
    fprintf(stderr, "can't create tmp file\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  unlink(template);

  if (write(fdtmp, buffer, strlen(buffer)) == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "can't write to the tmp file\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  /* Зачем использовать lseek здесь ? */
  if ((lseek(fdtmp, 0, SEEK_SET)) == -1) {
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer)); /* очистка буфера */
  while ((n = read(fdtmp, buffer, sizeof(buffer))) > 0) {
    if ((write(1, buffer, n)) != n) {
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
  }

  close(fdtmp);

  return 0;
}
```

Программа работает и в выводе получу `Hello World!` Просто не могу до конца понять зачем используется `lseek`. Объясните пожалуйста простым языком.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ну вот смотрите. указатель в файле изначально равен нулю. lseek меняет этот указатель. когда вы запишите данные в файл - указатель сместиться на количество записанных байт. чтобы прочитать эту строку, которую записали в файл, нужно перейти в начало файла, то есть использовать `lseek`.

Comment: спасибо большое за развёрнутый ответ, всё понятно!